# Dealing with huge data API-PLATFORM

Tags: nginx, bigdata, api-platform.com

I've an Entity called Companies that has a relation OneToMany with other Entity called CrmItems.

Entity/Company.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\CrmItems", mappedBy="company")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="`CompanyID`", referencedColumnName="`company_id`")
 */
private $crmItems;
```

Entity/CrmItems.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Companies", inversedBy="crmItems")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="company_id", referencedColumnName="`CompanyID`")
 */
private $company;
```

The problem here is, one company can have 11000 items.
Due to that when I request http://localhost:8080/companies/2 I got a 502 error

[image]

It seems that the headers size are too big related with X-Cache custom header size.

I've already searched through the internet even in API Platform Official docs https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.3/extra/troubleshooting/#upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream-502-error

The solution seems increasing the fastcgi buffers.

```
# Bigger buffer size to handle cache invalidation headers expansion
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
```

I already tried to increase without success.

There any trick to deal with huge data? API Platform supports relational collections pagination?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> API Platform supports relational collections pagination?

I never red about in the docs.

If it is really too big, I would think about an other design approach. Why not using CrmItems and filter for Company. This way you get them paginated.